# How can I extract and use information (values, string)... from a folder name in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I would like to create a batch file to organize my folder. This is basically my first time coding anything, sorry for the errors.

The folders name is composed of an integer and text, like this : "C:\bad folders\22my folder\"

In this instance, I would like to create new folders with the folder name's text and the file in the integer rank in alphabetical order.
Here, it would create the folder:

C:\finished folders\my folder

containing only the file

C:\finished folders\my folder\22.txt (the 22nd file inside the folder)

Here is what I've done until now, but it's absolutely terrible, I will try my best to fix it:

```
MKDIR C:\cleaned folders\
CD C:\bad folders\
            ::I will try and make a loop for all the folders in "C:\bad folders\"

set oldfoldername=%CD%  ::the whole folder name (number+text)
set newfoldername=  ::the text in the folder name
set number=     ::the number in the folder name

mkdir C:\cleaned folders\newfoldername
CD ..


copy C:\bad folders\oldfoldername C:\cleaned folders\newfoldername
CD C:\cleaned folders\newfoldername
      ::loop maybe for all the files in "C:\cleaned folders\newfoldername"
IF (filerank) neq %number% DEL (filerank)
```

So, how can I get this information from a folder name and use it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the `for` command see `for /?` in an open cmd window or [online](http://ss64.com/nt/for) especially the `for /d` variant to iterate through folders.

Comment: Also see `rem /?`. `::` is a malformed label. Type `goto /?`.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

:: make destination directory - note quotes as md x y will create directories x and y
MKDIR "U:\cleaned folders\"

:: Read each directoryname in turn from ...\bad folders\ and assign to %%a
:: Examine a dir listing in bare format (/b) of directories (/ad). 

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /ad /b "u:\sourcedir\bad folders"') DO (
  rem Note REM not :: within a code block (parenthesised sequence of lines)
  rem set oldfoldername to the name found
 SET "oldfoldername=%%a"
  rem partition into newfoldername and number
 CALL :split
  REM create new destination directory and MOVE file
 CALL :cre8move
)
GOTO :EOF

:split
:: initialise destination components
SET "number="
SET "newfoldername=%oldfoldername%"

:splitlp
:: See whether the first character of newfoldername is in the string 0..9
ECHO 0123456789|FIND "%newfoldername:~0,1%">NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :EOF 

:: first character is numeric - accumulate and remove
SET "number=%number%%newfoldername:~0,1%"
SET "newfoldername=%newfoldername:~1%"
GOTO splitlp

:cre8move
:: create new destination directory
MD "U:\cleaned folders\%newfoldername%"

:: we need to skip (number - 1) lines, so calculate
SET /a skiplines=%number% - 1

:: Read the directorylist (not including directorynames /a-d), skipping number-1 names
:: Move that file (You may want to COPY) and then terminate the loop
FOR /f "skip=%skiplines%delims=" %%q IN ('dir /a-d /b "u:\sourcedir\bad folders\%oldfoldername%\*"') DO (
 ECHO MOVE "u:\sourcedir\bad folders\%oldfoldername%\%%q" "U:\cleaned folders\%newfoldername%"&GOTO :eof
)
GOTO :eof
```

I believe that the above should fulfill your strange requirement. I hope the narration by way of comments is useful.

You don't say whether you want to MOVE or COPY the file. I've just `echo`ed the required line. Change as required.

Note that this won't work for a directory named where `number` is 0 or 1. It's not complex to fix those value if required, but the demonstration of the method for other values as narrated appears to be the object here.

Batch has interesting ideas about leading 0s, too. If you need to preserve leading 0s, then that adds a little more complication.

Batch syntax takes a little getting used to. Seemingly minor changes can be disastrous, so copy-and-paste to a text-editor is probably the best approach. Don't use a word-processor as they have a habit of reformatting the text in an attempt to make it seem logical.

Note that when an attempt is made to create a directory that already exists, an error message will be displayed. This is harmless but ugly. You can cause the error message to be suppressed by appending `2>nul` to each `MD ...` line.

Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N"

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering and even taking the time to make the whole batch for me! Your comments are really helpful and detailed too!
I'm not really sure what you did in the "splitlp" loop. How do ~ 0,1 and % work here?

Comment: In general, *commandname /?* from the prompt will yield (terse) documentation, so *set/?* shows documentation for `set`. `set "var2=%var:~m,n%"` is a substring operation. `m` is the start position. The first character in the string `var` is character `0`. `m` may be negative, meaning `characters from end`. `n` may be positive meaning `for this many chars`, negative meaning `to this many chars from the end` or omitted (and the comma too) meaning `to the end`.